# Setup of a many to many association with more than one Tag type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, polymorphic-associations

In my application I have 7 models. I want to make it so users can use 2 different types of tags to tag 3 different models many different times. The user also belongs to all of these models.

The `User`

The 2 Tag models are `Dog` and `Cat`

The 3 models that can have the Tags are `Store`, `Farm`, `House`

Than I have the `Tagging` model to make the join table so it's a many to many since I want a Cat to be able to be assigned to a Store, Farm or House.

I wanted to know if what I have below is the correct way for this scenario. Should I have one `Tagging` join table or make another for each type of `Tag`? That being the Dog and Cat?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :stores
  has_many :houses
  has_many :farms
  has_many :cats
  has_many :taggings
end

class Dog/Cat < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :houses, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "House" 
   has_many :farms, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Farm" 
   has_many :stores, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Store" 
end

class House/Farm/Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :dogs, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Dog" 
  has_many :cats, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Cat" 
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :taggable_id, :taggable_type
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :cat
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end

# Tagging Table

create_table :taggings do |t|
   t.integer :dog_id
   t.integer :cat_id
   t.integer :user_id
   t.integer :taggable_id
   t.string  :taggable_type
end
```

Comment: How different are you `Cat` and `Dog` models from one another?

Comment: @ThomasKleem Their pretty different, I have about 5 different columns for the `Cat` so far and 3 for the `Dog`.

Comment: What exactly is a tagging? What does it represent?

Comment: @NielsB. Dog and Cat Tags and Tagging itself is the join table between a Dog or Cat and a House/Farm or Store.

Comment: Can a dog and a cat share the same building?

Comment: @NielsB. Yeah it's a many to many.

Answer (score 1):

### Some thoughts on your design

#### Why must users own tags?

It seems that the animals are the real owners of the tags. And seeing as the animals are owned by users, it seems redundant to associate users with tags.

#### The tags don't belong to dogs or cats, they belong to animals.

Seeing as tags can only be owned by either a cat or a dog, it seems unintuitive to refer both as a foreign key. If you add a rabbit later on, would you make another association? I would explore a polymorphic solution in which tags belong to animals. This will automatically eliminate the concern of one tag belonging to both a cat and a dog.

Comment: I'm still confused here. I do have a polymorphic association above. The Dog and Cat could be the same as `Tag` if this was normal tagging with just one model. But, in my case I have 2 `Tag` models called `Cat` and `Dog`. I'm using `Tagging` as the join table and this table is used for both of them just to simplify things so I don't have to make 2 `Tagging` tables - one for the `Dog` and one for the `Cat`.  I also want the tags to have an actually owner because information about a `Dog` or `Cat` would be that owners. These models have more columns to them than what I've shown.

Comment: I totally redid my question to make sense of what I'm getting at.

Comment: I would probably go the same route as you, except I would make the tag's owner (cat/dog) a polymorphic association, like I wrote. It will make your code simpler, because you won't have to check for the presence of either cat or dog, you can just do @tag.animal.

Comment: Also, I would consider inheritance options. Can store, farm or house be united under a building superclass?

And if you are worried about performance, you might want to ask yourself if a SQL database is the right choice for your application.